# Rename a jquery function

Tags: jquery

```
$('#up').click(function(){$('#fn').click();});
```

I was wondering if it is possible to rename/define the `.click()` to something else, like `.xclick()`.

Comment: What exactly would the event `xclick` stand for? The `click` on JQuery is not a function its an event, which is triggered by specific actions on the browser.

Comment: apologies. xclick() suppose to work like click().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be just defining a `function` that does what you want:

```
function xclick(selector, callback) {
  $(selector).click(callback);
}

xclick('#up', function(){ $('#fn').click(); });
```

But if you want to use `jQuery`s interface you can use it's prototype:

```
$.fn.xclick = $.fn.click

$('#up').xclick(function(){$('#fn').click();});
```

Comment: The second option works, but what about the one inside it? I want to have all the click() to xclick().

Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a function by assigning a new property and then deleting the old reference or reassigning the old reference.

However, in your example this concept would be a terrible one. I wouldn't make sense. By changing the very API of such a public library your entire page/site/app would be broken. Not only that but anyone using your code would no longer be able to rely on jQuery. Even jQuery could no longer rely on itself.

You would be better off making your own jQuery plugin and not attempt to change the expected behavior of the existing library. in otherwords, extend don't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event namespaces with `.on`:

`$('#something').on('click.x', function(){
    //
});`

`$('#something').on('click.y', function(){
    //
});`